# Highcharts: when i export a graph I get the dialog which says: "are you sure you want to navigate ..."

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart with exporting enabled.  When I click to download a png, jpeg, etc, I get the message "are you sure you want to navigate...".  I have overridden the default URL for exporting to be local to my web app (relative "mvc/...").  Since I have overridden the URL to be local, I would not expect to see this message and do not want to see it.

Any suggestions on what to do would be greatly appreciated.

paul

Comment: Does your page define a `window.onbeforeunload` function?

Comment: My page does not.  i am not sure if Highcharts does.  Should i define this function?

Comment: Something has to be defining it; Highcharts does not.  You could try nulling it out: `window.onbeforeunload = null`

Comment: i'll check into it, thanks

Comment: I did a search on it & found it referenced in jquery.min.js which was brought in as part of highcharts.

Comment: I will try setting it to null.